# How do I use a ByteTensor in a contrastive cosine loss function?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implement the loss function in http://anthology.aclweb.org/W16-1617 in PyTorch. It is shown as follows:

[image]

I've implemented the loss as follows:

```
class CosineContrastiveLoss(nn.Module):
    """
    Cosine contrastive loss function.
    Based on: http://anthology.aclweb.org/W16-1617
    Maintain 0 for match, 1 for not match.
    If they match, loss is 1/4(1-cos_sim)^2.
    If they don't, it's cos_sim^2 if cos_sim < margin or 0 otherwise.
    Margin in the paper is ~0.4.
    """

    def __init__(self, margin=0.4):
        super(CosineContrastiveLoss, self).__init__()
        self.margin = margin

    def forward(self, output1, output2, label):
        cos_sim = F.cosine_similarity(output1, output2)
        loss_cos_con = torch.mean((1-label) * torch.div(torch.pow((1.0-cos_sim), 2), 4) +
                                    (label) * torch.pow(cos_sim * torch.lt(cos_sim, self.margin), 2))
        return loss_cos_con
```

However, I'm getting an error saying:

`TypeError: mul received an invalid combination of arguments - got (torch.cuda.ByteTensor), but expected one of:
 * (float value)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (torch.cuda.ByteTensor)
 * (torch.cuda.FloatTensor other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (torch.cuda.ByteTensor)`

I know that `torch.lt()` returns a ByteTensor, but if I try to coerce it to a FloatTensor with `torch.Tensor.float()` I get `AttributeError: module 'torch.autograd.variable' has no attribute 'FloatTensor'`.

I'm really not sure where to go from here. It seems logical to me to do an element-wise multiplication between the cosine similarity tensor and a tensor with 0 or 1 based on a less-than rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try float() method on the variable directly?
Variable(torch.zeros(5)).float() - works for me, for instance

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question has time, but as many I have come here to find how to use the "cosine similarity" in a contrastive loss.
The formula that they expose in the article does not seem correct to me.

If you look at the operator "<" of formula 13, Ew < m in figure (2) of the article can never be happen. I think that equation 13 is the following:

[image]

Plot of the equation (13) of the article (It does not look like Figure 2):
[Wrong (13) equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoLbJ.png)

Plot of the equation of the equivalent to figure 2 (m=0.4):
[Correct (13) equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeUJ7.png)